# How can I replace my input field with edited data in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have to edit the input field.When I click on edit button,input field should appear and when I have entered the data in input text box,entered data has to be replaced inplace of input text box.Here is my code but Iam not getting the result.How can I get the result?

```js
 $scope.options = function () {
        $scope.showBatch = !$scope.showBatch;
        $scope.val = $scope.batchNumber;
        
        document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = $scope.val;

    }
```

```html
<span id="b1" style="font-size:25px">Batch</span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-right" ng-click="options()"></span>
                        <input type="text" ng-show="showBatch" ng-model="batchNumber">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

Html

```
<span id="b1" ng-show="!showBatch" style="font-size:25px">{{batchNumber}}</span>
<input type="text" ng-show="showBatch" ng-model="batchNumber">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-right" ng-click="options()"></span>
```

Angular Controller

```
    $scope.batchNumber = "Batch";
    $scope.options = function () {
        $scope.showBatch = !$scope.showBatch;
        $scope.val = $scope.batchNumber;
    }
```